# index out of range while saving user data - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, indexpath

To preface, I am new to programming and Swift.

I am following a tutorial and am learning to save user data. Only when the save encoder/decoder functionality is enabled will this crash occur.

Here is the encoding and decoding:

```
    override func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(clickCount, forKey: "clickCount")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        clickCount = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "clickCount") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
    }
```

I am trying to increment the array at the indexPath.row of the clickCount array to know how many times a user clicks on a cell in my tableView

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
            
            vc.selectedImage = pictures[indexPath.row]
            
            vc.totalPictures = pictures.count
            
            vc.selectedPictureNumber = (pictures.firstIndex(of: vc.selectedImage ?? "Error") ?? 0) + 1

            clickCount[indexPath.row] += 1
            
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            
        }
        
    }
```

And finally, here is the clickCount array

```
    var clickCount = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

To be clear, incrementing the array works as expected when I comment out the encoder and decoder functionality, but I want to save how many times each row has been clicked between sessions.

Comment: make sure the `clickCount` has the same number of elements as your `pictures` array.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It does. I think it has something to do with the encode functionality as commenting that out causes it to not error out.